# Unable to write or append data into csv in imacros

Tags: export-to-csv, imacros

I'm extracting some data using imacros, and trying to append that data into a csv.
This is my code for extraction

```
'Gives me a numeric value(e.g  14)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=CLASS:proPriceField&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/[0-9,]+/);")

'Gives me a numeric value(e.g  2456)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=CLASS:sqrPriceField&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET abc EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/[0-9,]+/);")

'Gives me a text value(e.g "Kalyan")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=CLASS:localityFirst&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT

'Gives me lattiude from a link
TAG POS=2 TYPE=a ATTR=class:stop-propagation&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET lat EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\?(lat=.+?)&/)[1];")

'Gives me longitude from a link
SET longt EVAL("var regex = /longt=(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)/g; var str = '{{!EXTRACT}}';str.match(regex)[1];")

SAVEAS TYPE=!EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=temp.csv
```

This is the [link](http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&Locality=Kalyan&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=10-Lacs&BudgetMax=30-Lacs) from where I'm extracting data.

I'm expecting data should be appended in the following format

```
ProPrice   SqrPrice  Locality    Lat      Longt
 14        2456       Kalyan    19.456    17.897
```

But the above code gives error `"reject is not defined, line: 20 (Error code: -1001)"` while writing data in csv, Any suggestion on why is it happening. Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your code a little:

```
'Gives me a numeric value(e.g  14)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=CLASS:proPriceField&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET ProPrice EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/[0-9,]+/);")
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Gives me a numeric value(e.g  2456)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=CLASS:sqrPriceField&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET SqrPrice EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/[0-9,]+/);")
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Gives me a text value(e.g "Kalyan")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=CLASS:localityFirst&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET Locality {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Gives me lattiude from a link
TAG POS=2 TYPE=a ATTR=class:stop-propagation&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET lat EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\?(lat=.+?)&/)[1];")

'Gives me longitude from a link
SET longt EVAL("var regex = /longt=(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)/g; var str = '{{!EXTRACT}}';str.match(regex)[1];")

SET !EXTRACT {{ProPrice}}[EXTRACT]{{SqrPrice}}[EXTRACT]{{Locality}}[EXTRACT]{{lat}}[EXTRACT]{{longt}}

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=temp.csv
```

Comment: the code is completely running fine it exported the data into csv except the fact that it's not giving the column name while exporting, pardon for replying it so late.